# Why isn't this Bixby text displaying in color?

Tags: bixby

I am trying to make a title display in color but it is not minding me.  I see in the documentation where it explains that colors clash with Soft but this is not a soft Style.

https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.render.layout.section.content.map-card.title-area.slot3.single-line.text.color

I also see that perhaps titles should not be colored (as colors are for status changes?) but I feel this title needs a bit more ornamentation. Ideas?

```
render {
    layout {
      section {
        content { 
          title-area
          { 
          slot1 {
              text {
                color (Blue)
                { style (Title_M)
                }
                value ("#{value(this.title)}")
              }
          }

        }
      }
      }
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Nilay Patel gave me this, which worked. I had forgotten to include the single-line directive before  text { ....

```
render {
    layout {
      section {
        content { 
          title-area
          { 
          slot1 {
              **single-line**: text {
                color (Blue)
                style (Title_M)
                value ("#{value(this.title)}")
              }
          }

        }
      }
      }
```